# Choosing when to have open and closed brackets using Cut in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to cut a column from a table to 3 sizes - small, medium and big. I've got this so far:

```
apartments$sizes <- cut(apartments$m2, c(0,60,90,max(apartments$m2)), Right = T, include.lowest = T)
```

This gives me:

```
Levels: [0,60] (60,90] (90,618]
```

What I want is

```
Levels: [0,60) [60,90] (90,618]
```

Can anyone help me to reach the desired result?

Comment: `cut()` only allows intervals closed on the left OR closed on the right. You might try different breaks to achieve such a behaviour.

Comment: Do you have any alternative in mind @ottlngr

Comment: Using `breaks = c(0,59,90,max(apartments$m2))` yields `(0,59] (59,90] (90,618]` - isn't that (roughly) the same as `[0,60) [60,90] (90,618]`?